# Suddenly Chrome started blocking popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an affiliate website for which redirect is the most critical part. I used a simple script to pop open links in a new window. But since last week suddenly chrome started blocking these popups.

```js
$(".get-code").click(function() {
  $couponId = $(this).attr("data-coupon-id");
  $url = $(this).attr("data-coupon-url");
  $outUrl = $(this).attr("data-out-url");
  //alert("Coupon Id: " + $couponId + " URL: " + $url + " Redirect URL: " + $outUrl);
  window.open($outUrl, '_self');
  window.open($url, '_blank');
});
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Why not  `window.open($url, '_blank'); location.replace($outUrl)`

Comment: Chrome 75 rollout has been happening over the last couple of weeks, so it's likely a new/tightened security restriction in place blocking opening multiple popups programmatically, which isn't a good idea really.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah I believe so. these popups are the key thing. can you suggest something to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by breaking both the redirection into two parts.
One redirection is done on the click event and another one is using the href link of the anchor tag. This way chrome doesn't block it and also works fine in IE and Firefox.

```
<a rel="noopener noreferrer" onclick="return hitTarget('URL1')" href="URL2" >GRAB CODE</a>
```

JavaScript redirection

```
function hitTarget(target){
    window.open(target,'_blank');
    return true;
}
```